# sort not working for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown in my angular.js webapp like:

```
<select ng-model="script"
        ng-options="s as s[1].shortDescription for s in objs | orderBy:'toString()'" 
        ng-change="updateParam()">
</select>
```

where the objects in the array are type of

```
["test1", {shortDescription: "first test", longDescription: "AAAAAAAA"}]
```

I want to sort by `shortDescription` property of each entry. The problem is that the sort doesn't work.

**UPDATE1**

Sample data

```
["test1", {shortDescription: "first test", longDescription: "AAAAAAAA"}]
["test2", {shortDescription: "2nd test", longDescription: "BBBB"}]
["test3", {shortDescription: "3rd test", longDescription: "CCCC"}]
```

Comment: Array index in ng-options looks suspicious. OrderBy should be followed by property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the following

```
| orderBy: 'shortDescription'
```

Where you are sorting by property `shortDescription`. See the [orderBy docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for more information. Here is a simplistic example demonstrating this...

```
<select ng-model="script"
        ng-options="s as s.shortDescription for s in objs | orderBy: 'shortDescription'">
</select>
```

---

```
$scope.objs = [{shortDescription: "first test", longDescription: "AAAAAAAA"},
               {shortDescription: "aaa short", longDescription: "BBBBBB"}]
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dg7wL9yk/) - working example

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Wonder if there is a workaround where we don't change the format of the object array?  Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun can you post your sample data with multiple entries? Perhaps I am not understanding your structure correctly

Comment: just added a update the question with multiple entries.  Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun this should have been the accepted answer. The other suggestion simply references mine. You needed to changed your structure anyways, and if the data structure was such a concern, I'd say that is a good candidate for a new question. You wanted a way to order your results and this is the way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @sal niro is demonstrating, the orderBy filter works on objects (order by a property of an object) your sample data shows that you are iterating over an array of array, which on the first position there's a string and in the second there's an object, forget about the object, you have an array of array, which it does not have properties, just elements, theres no way you can tell the filter to order by a property of one on the elements of an array, as far as i know :).

The best possible solution is to convert that array of arrays to an array of objects, in which each object have a title, shortDescription and a longDescription.

```
{
    title: 'test1',
    shortDescription: 'a',
    longDescription: 'aaaaaaaa'
}
```

Comment: I took the pain and made the change on the data format and now it works ok. Thanks to you and @sal niro.

Comment: I don't understand how this is the accepted answer. The question was how to filter the items in `ng-options` which my answer addresses. This suggestion addressed a minor concern about your data structure- which you needed to change anyways as you saw in my answer. @codingFun

Comment: @sal niro,  wish I could accept both answers:-)  I accepted this answer because it makes me to take the pain and change the format from `["test1",  {shortDescription: "a", longDescription: "aaaaaaa"}]` to  the format `{title: 'test1',shortDescription: 'a',longDescription: 'aaaaaaaa'}`.

Comment: @codingFun and so did my suggestion. Either way you needed to modify your structure. If I delete my answer, anyone who visits this question will likely have no idea what is going on. This could have been condensed to a comment. Anyways... happy coding

Comment: @sal niro, the question was why orderBy was not working for him, not how to use the orderBy filter.

Comment: You know what, its yours, you have the privilege of have the correct answer, I don't care, i was just trying to help this guy to solve his problem, it doesn't really matter, @codingFun I'm glad that you resolved your issue, read you later! ✌️

Comment: @salniro, I accepted your answer. Also appreciate Chichozell's answer because it gave me the idea/resolve to change the format of the data.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @Chichozell I apologize if I upset you. I just felt as a minor extension to my answer, a comment would have been more appropriate. Adding a `title` field to the same structure I posted (which... at the time, I didn't know `title` existed per OP's question) is trivial to solve at that point

Comment: this is funny, you know that "new" users dont have the privilege to comment on any answer right?, looks like by having this "conversation" about who's right and who's not, i earned that privilege, sorry for not be able to comment on your answer @sal niro, next time i will, now that i can ;D

Comment: @Chichozell hey man I totally overlooked that in respect to the comment everywhere privilege, now this makes more sense and I'll admit I was overly harsh about it. I wonder if this has ever been taken up on meta